# Printing the results of an increasing cumulative loop as a single data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, linear-discriminant

I've been running a least discriminant analysis on the results of a principal components analysis in R, and I've been calculating the appropriate number of PCs to use based on the minimum number of PCs that represent a certain threshhold of cumulative variation that return the highest reclassification rate, following the methodology in some previous studies.

I have been calculating the reclassification rates for the various cumulative numbers of PCs using a loop, but wish to print it as a data.frame for an RMarkdown report. This is the code I have been using.

```
for (j in 1:21){
  vars<-sum(diag(prop.table(table(
    trainingframe$locus,
    lda(data.frame(trainingframe[-c(1)])[1:j],grouping=trainingframe$locus,CV=TRUE,prior = c(1,1,1)/3)$class))))
  print(data.frame(j,vars))
}
```

In this code `trainingframe` is the training dataset, and `locus` is the categorical variable of interest the lda is interested in classifying. The first column is not selected because it is the locus. I can't provide the original data but this should be reprexable on any dataset that contains the principal components of a number of variables and then some categorical variable of interest for classification.

This is the results I get from the script.

```
  j     vars
1 1 0.512605
  j      vars
1 2 0.5882353
  j      vars
1 3 0.7058824
  j      vars
1 4 0.6806723
  j      vars
1 5 0.6722689
  j      vars
1 6 0.6638655
  j      vars
1 7 0.6722689
  j      vars
1 8 0.6386555
  j      vars
1 9 0.6470588
   j      vars
1 10 0.6554622
   j      vars
1 11 0.6554622
   j      vars
1 12 0.7226891
   j      vars
1 13 0.7142857
   j      vars
1 14 0.6890756
   j      vars
1 15 0.6806723
   j      vars
1 16 0.6806723
   j      vars
1 17 0.6890756
   j      vars
1 18 0.6554622
   j      vars
1 19 0.6470588
```

However, as you can see, the printed result prints a number of independent data frames for each result rather than one dataframe containing the results of all of the analyses.

What I'd like to produce is a data.frame like the following...

```
 j      vars
 1 0.5126050
 2 0.5882353
 3 0.7058824
 4 0.6806723
 5 0.6722689
 6 0.6638655
 7 0.6722689
 8 0.6386555
 9 0.6470588
10 0.6554622
11 0.6554622
12 0.7226891
13 0.7142857
14 0.6890756
15 0.6806723
16 0.6806723
17 0.6890756
18 0.6554622
19 0.6470588
```

I am trying to figure out a way to rewrite the above code to produce the last data frame shown here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can initialize a dataset and then `rbind` instead of `print`ing

```
d1 <- data.frame(j = integer(), vars = numeric())
for (j in 1:21){
  vars<-sum(diag(prop.table(table(
    trainingframe$locus,
    lda(data.frame(trainingframe[-c(1)])[1:j],
               grouping=trainingframe$locus,CV=TRUE,
              prior = c(1,1,1)/3)$class))))
 d1 <- rbind(d1, data.frame(j,vars))
}
```

---

Or another way to write the code is with `lapply`

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:21, function(j) {
      cls <- lda(data.frame(trainingframe[-1])[seq_len(j)],
         grouping = trainingframe$locus, CV = TRUE,
          prior = c(1, 1, 1)/3)$class
       vars <- sum(diag(prop.table(table(trainingframe$locus, cls))))
       data.frame(j, vars)
      }))
```